# Verifying a .tar.gz backup

Tags: backup, tar

**Edit 3:** For people who will read this question: `--verify` mysteriously fails with *"Warning: Cannot seek: Illegal seek"*, hence I recommend you look for alternative ways to verify your archives.  My original question follows.

---

Short of restoring it, what is a proper way to ensure the integrity of a `.tar.gz` backup?  I'm using `GNU tar`.

According to the man page of `tar` and to what I have read around, `tar` offers a `--verify` option while creating an archive and a `--diff` option to find differences between an existing archive and the file system.

Is a check with `--diff` redundant right after creating an archive with `--verify`?  Or is `--diff` more reliable and hence a previous `--verify` is redundant, unless you want your backup procedure to fail fast?

Should we invoke `gzip --test` as well to verify the `.gz` archive, or does `tar` perform such a check on its own already, both with `--verify` and `--diff`?  I would say it does.

Thanks for your attention.

**Edit:** As suggested by Lgeorget, I could store an hash of the archive as well, to check at restoration time that the archive has not been corrupted.

**Edit 2:** Hence, apparently `--verify` would be enough.  Maybe I could use `tar --list` to check that the archive is readable and extractable.  I also wonder whether `--diff` checks the contents of files or just their names (and possibly attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a diff after a verify is redundant, and no, there is no point to `gzip --test`, as the first thing tar has to do to read the archive is ungzip it, so any problems with the compression would cause a failure there.

Answer (score 2):

`--diff` is more intended for backups purposes. For example, to check if it's necessary to `tar` a directory again when you schedule a periodic backup.

I have no clue about the efficiency of the `--verify` option. If you have doubt about it, or want to be able to check the integrity of your `tar` later, you can use a hash.

For example:

```
> sha1sum etc.tar.gz 
b30d837c623274908de2ebaceb72b07c54037546  etc.tar.gz
```

Then store this line to a file (let's call it `etc.tar.gz.checksum`). And when you want to check the integrity, move this file to the directory where `etc.tar.gz` is and run:

```
> sha1sum -c etc.tar.gz.checksum 
etc.tar.gz: OK
```

`sha1sum` is provided with `openssl`.

Comment: Here, I am not concerned about the integrity of an archive: I'm concerned whether its content matches the file-system, while performing backups.  Thanks for your suggestion about using an hash, though: I have added it to my question.

Comment: Well, I suppose I'm being extra careful, here, because most of the guides on backups - that I've read - don't bother to verify the generated archives.